# GeoServer v2.9.1 re-sampling errors with GetCoverage request

Tags: raster, geoserver, openlayers, resampling, wcs

**App**

I'm using Openlayers3 and GeoServer 2.9.1 to create an application allowing users to draw an aoi then download it as raw data subsets (geotiff) of a Canada wide data set (also geotiff). I'm using a WCS 1.0.0 GetCoverage request where bbox and Grid Dimensions are dynamically entered.

**Issue**

When validating the subsets, a simple subtraction of the downloaded data from the original dataset reveals pixel value changes (see image). How can I retrieve raw data subsets without re-sampling errors? It is critical that the pixel values be identical to the original.

Making a GetCoverage request from GeoServer's Demo Request Builder using the same bbox coords as my script gives me the same errors.

*Pixel value difference from rasterCalc* 
[image: Pixel value difference]

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a WCS 1.0 request that is not subsampling is pretty hard, it has to match precisely the data set. Better make a WCS 2.0 request, that should give you a much better chance of just performing a pixel by pixel extraction.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update this post when I get to the bottom of it, but that's a good suggestion to explore.